# Excel: Conditional formatting not filling in cells if adjacent cell is filled

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am trying to fill a pair of cells in if both are blank. Which works unless the cell next to the pair is filled in. How do I go about resolving this issue?

Formula:

=AND(ISBLANK(F2),ISBLANK(G2))

Applies to :

=$F$2:$G$4

[image: Example of issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem occurs because the formula you use looks at the columns with "relative reference". That is, unless you specify that the cells you want to check are always in columns F and G by using the dollar-sign (`$`), the cells the conditional formatting checks will be offset with the same amount of rows and columns as they are removed from the top left cell in the range you are applying the conditional formatting to.

In other words, changing the formula to `=AND(ISBLANK($F2),ISBLANK($G2))` will solve your issue.